# can't insert into database using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a meeting system hat checks the schedule of the participants and room in order to create a meeting and I have a problem when adding the participants of the meeting into the database it only enters one user don't know why

here is my php code

```
$dbhost = "127.0.0.1";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "mss";
$connection = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
if (mysql_errno()) {
    die("Database Connection failed:" . mysql_error() . "(" . mysql_errno() . ")");
}
mysql_select_db('mss');
?>
<?php echo $id = (isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : "hello"); ?> <br>
<?php echo $title = (isset($_POST['title']) ? $_POST['title'] : "hello"); ?> <br>
<?php echo $employee = (isset($_POST['employee']) ? $_POST['employee'] : "hello"); ?> <br>
<?php
$participant = (isset($_POST['participant']) ? $_POST['participant'] : "hello");
$starttime = (isset($_POST['starttime']) ? $_POST['starttime'] : "hello");
$endtime = (isset($_POST['endtime']) ? $_POST['endtime'] : "hello");
$day = (isset($_POST['day']) ? $_POST['day'] : "hello");
$room = (isset($_POST['room']) ? $_POST['room'] : "hello");
$Lines = explode("\n", $participant);
foreach ($Lines as $line) 
{
    echo $line;
    $q1 = "select Availability from E_schedule where Employee_name='$line' and StartTime='$starttime' and Day='$day'";
    $q2 = "SELECT Availability from room_schedule WHERE r_name = '$room' AND StartTime='$starttime' and Day='$day'";
    $result = mysql_query($q1, $connection);
    $result1 = mysql_query($q2, $connection);
    if ($result == FALSE)
    {
        die(mysql_error());
    }
    if ($result1 == FALSE)
    {
        die(mysql_error());
    }
        $info = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $info1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1);
        if ($info['Availability'] == 1) {
            echo ("You can't make a meeting at that time, Please Select another Day or time");
        }           
        if ($info1['Availability'] == 1) {
            echo ("You can't make a meeting at that Room, Please Select another Room");
        }
    else
    {
        $insert_meeting="insert into E_schedule (Employee_name, StartTime, EndTime, Day, Availability, Activity_Name) values ('$line', '$starttime ', '$endtime', '$day', '1', '$title')";
        $insert_result = mysql_query($insert_meeting, $connection );
        if($insert_result == FALSE) 
        {
            die(mysql_error()); 
        }
        $meeting="insert into meeting (Title, StartTime, EndTime, Day, Participant, Room) values ('$title', '$starttime ', '$endtime', '$day', '$participant','$room')";
        $meeting_result = mysql_query($meeting, $connection );
        if($meeting_result == FALSE) 
        {
            die(mysql_error()); 
        }
        $insert_room="insert into room_schedule (r_name,M_Title, StartTime, EndTime, Day, Availability) values ('$room','$title','$starttime ', '$endtime', '$day', '1')";
        $insert_result1 = mysql_query($insert_room, $connection );
        if($insert_result1 == FALSE) 
        {
            die(mysql_error()); 
        }
        echo ("The Meeting has been Created Successfully"); 
    }
}
?>
<br><?php echo $day = (isset($_POST['day']) ? $_POST['day'] : "hello"); ?> <br>
<?php echo $starttime = (isset($_POST['starttime']) ? $_POST['starttime'] : "hello"); ?><br>
<?php echo $endtime = (isset($_POST['endtime']) ? $_POST['endtime'] : "hello"); ?><br>
<?php echo $room = (isset($_POST['room']) ? $_POST['room'] : "hello"); ?> <br>
</body>
</html>
```

can you please help
I tried so many thing and it is not working
thanks in advance

Comment: What is the error you getting ?

Comment: there is no error message but the participants are not entered in the database only the first one

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to pass the $dbname in the mysql_connect function.

```
$dbhost = "127.0.0.1";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "mss";
$connection = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
```

i need more information to figure out the issue. post the error message which you are receiving

Comment: there is no error message but the participants are not entered in the database only the first one

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you're using depreciated mysql?

Use PHP5.x:

- [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo)
- [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/mysqli)

Next, I may have missed it; but I don't see you sanitizing your user inputs; that is not a safe thing to do.

As for your exact problem,
I'm only seeing the one post value for `$participant`. So, I'm assuming you're only gathering the first result from the field name.